# MySQL 5.3 unhandled error from mysql_next_result()

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute 4 transaction at once

```
UPDATE tableA set F1 = 'ABC' WHERE F1 ='OLD;
DELETE FROM tableB WHERE F1 = 'OLD';
DELETE FROM tableC WHERE F1 = 'OLD';
```

I am getting the follow error:

```
[ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.19-log]unhandled error from mysql_next_result()
myodbc5w.dll 

 -->    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult(Boolean disposing, Boolean allresults)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, 

Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)

   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)

   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have try to put on connection string : "`;CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS=TRUE"` with no results.

With MS SQL Server we can perform multiple transaction.

Comment: Maybe your library of choice doesn`t not support multiple statements?

Answer (score 1):

After all investigating the message on the ODBC exception its not clear.
If something in one of your transaction comes up with any error you will get unhandled error from "mysql_next_result()" that's lead you to lost focus on what is going on.

In this case we try to delete something that's violated references integrate "a foreign key constraint fails"

If you get this "mysql_next_result()" on multiple transaction make sure you run each statement separately.